# Git: How to ignore files on Windows?

Tags: windows, git

I create .gitignore in folder with my repository near .git

```
project
--.git
--.gitignore
--Source
----tmp
----scr
```

But git doesn`t see it, wouldn`t ignore files in .gitignore

My .gitignore file:

```
*.tmp
*~
*.pdb
*.user
*.suo
Sources/tmp
```

What`s wrong?

**Up:**
I created new repositiry, add .gitignore before init commit -  it work!
But if I add in old repository it doesn`t...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're specifying glob syntax when the default syntax for git is regex.

Try this instead:

```
.*\.tmp
.*~
.*\.pdb
.*\.user
.*\.suo
Sources\/tmp
```

Comment: No it doesn't. You are probably thinking of Mercurial.

Comment: Hrm, could have sworn it was Git :) Ah well!

Comment: Mate, if it deserves a downvote I have no problem with it :) That's what SO is about eh? :-D

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work, though your directory listing has `Source/` while your `.gitignore` has `Sources/`.

The one thing that springs to mind is that the line endings might not be what git is expecting.

Also, as tmp is a directory, usually a trailing '/' is used:

> Source/tmp/

Finally, you can also create a .gitignore in `Source/` with the line:

> tmp/
>   instead of having it in the top directory.

Comment: @mystdeim: I really do expect it to be a line-endings issue.